# htaccess getting values from a subdomain and redirecting to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a url setup like so

sub.domain.com/leaderboards/showlist/APPNAME/SCORE/DEVICEID

I'm trying to use the htaccess in the root of the website not the sub domain to foward that url to

domain2.com/get/APPNAME/leaderboards/SCORE/DEVICEID

I'm able to get this to work when I use this code in the subdomain htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^showList/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ http://domain2.com/get/$1/leaderboard/$2/$3/ [NC,L]
```

However this doesn't work in the root htaccess so I've tried a little bit of everything I found online and I can't figure out how to get the params like above. This is what it currently looks like and it doesn't do anything at all

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^showList/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ http://domain2.com/get/$1/leaderboard/$2/$3 [NC,L]
```

From my understanding the RewriteCond should only include people on the sub domain and the rule should work the same as it does in the sub domain htaccess right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're running into is that now you have the `.htaccess` file in a different directory.

The directive `RewriteRule` matches relative to the current directory so let's say the subdomain is in a folder called `sub` which is under the parent directory (which now contains the .htaccess), you'd need to match using `RewriteRule ^sub/showList` I believe.

Another way you could do it to keep things simple would be do your matches in `RewriteCond` against `%{REQUEST_URI}` and then use % backreferences to refer to those matches. See the example below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/showList/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ 
RewriteRule .* http://domain2.com/get/%1/leaderboard/%2/%3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hmm I see what you're doing and I think I understand it fully but no matter what I do I keep getting:

The requested URL /leaderboards/showList/APPNAME/SCORE/DEVICEID was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: @Dave Oh, you're missing `R` to redirect it.  Try changing `[NC,L]` to `[NC,L,R]`.  After you're done developing and know it works, if this should be a permanent redirection (good for SEO), you can use `[NC,L,R=301]`